# setup subdomain Apache not working properly

Tags: apache-2.2

when i setup subdomain in apache config file, i check the subdomain it works fine however when i check the directories in my main domain the it tells server not found how can i add the subdomain and make sure that both of them are working?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName amg.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/amg.domain.com/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you directory permissions setup correctly? Do they have the  correct SELinux Security context? What does the error message say? Any helpful information in the log files?

Comment: SELINUX=enforcing, yes these folder are setup correctly and the error msg tells that the link that im looking for not found and it shows that apache shows wrong path: File does not exist: /var/www/amg.domain.com/html/im3 while this folder exist in this path /var/www/html/im3

Comment: which apache version you are using? if 2.2 you need to add NameVirtualHost *:80 outside the virtualhost code

Comment: yes it is, can you show me the right code or guide for that?

Comment: What does `apachectl -S` say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below apache virtualhost and replace "ip_address" with real IP

```
NameVirtualHost ip_address:80

<VirtualHost ip_address:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog logs/error.log
    CustomLog logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip_address:80>
    ServerName amg.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/amg.domain.com/html

    ErrorLog logs/subdomain_error.log
    CustomLog logs/subdomain_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Syntax error on line 1017 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" clause
both should be on the same ip.

Comment: I've updated answer

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: Comment CustomLog directive and check again.